# Using sort() to get numbers in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to complete this [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/descending-order/train/javascript). Trying to figure it out, I've seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676888/javascript-sorting-numbers) but I think I'm doing it as it says in there.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it sort the numbers in descending order?
This is my code so far:

```
function descendingOrder(n){
  let newN = n.toString().split(' ').sort(function(a,b){return b-a}).join();
  return parseInt(newN);
}
```

Test Passed: Value == 0
Test Passed: Value == 1
Expected: 987654321, instead got: 123456789

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest splitting your variable assignment into several lines. Assign each intermediate step to a variable and print the value of the variable. Use `console.log()`. For more debugging tips, see [this blog article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `n.toString().split('').sort(function(a,b){return b-a}).join('');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to split the string with an empty string `''` to get single digits and join it with an empty string.

Splitting with a character which is not part of the string results in an array with a single value. A later joined array returns this single element. That is why you get the same value as result as the input.

[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) without a specified separator, returns a comma separated string with the values.

```
let newN = n.toString().split('').sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; }).join('');
```

At the end, you could take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), like

```
return +newN;
```

for getting an numerical value.

BTW, with the use of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you may specify a radix, because strings with leading zero may be converted to an octal number.

Comment: I've never seen '+' been used before to convert to a number, but seems very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## Here is an explained answer

[image]

```
function descendingOrder(n) {
  let result = n
    .toString() // convert numbers to string
    .split('') // split each string char in to an array of chars
    .sort((a, b) => b - a) // sort that array descending
    .join('') // regroup all items in that array into 1 string

  return parseInt(result) // turn the group of strings into an array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function descendingOrder(n){
  return +('' + n).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers have already stated you will need to call [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with an empty string to properly create an array containing each character.

Also, when I tested join() I noticed commas in the output (chrome 65).  I added a [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function to strip the commas, which passed the test.

```
function descendingOrder(n){
  let newN = n.toString().split('').sort(function(a,b){return b-a}).join().replace(/,/g,'');
  return parseInt(newN);
}
```